# How can I detect the lines of code between the parentheses of this CREATE TABLE SQL?

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

From the following code I need to extract only what is in parentheses, without consuming these.

```
create table if not exists `va_lottery`.`iso_4217`
(
    ccodealpha char(3) not null comment 'ISO alpha.',
    ccodenumeric char(3) not null comment 'ISO numeric',
    cminorunit varchar(4) default 0 comment 'Minor unit.',
    cname varchar(80) not null comment 'Name of the currency.',
    centity varchar(100) not null comment 'Entity.'
)
engine=innodb comment='ISO codes of coins.';
```

That is to say. only extract the following lines of code.

```
    ccodealpha char(3) not null comment 'ISO alpha.',
    ccodenumeric char(3) not null comment 'ISO numeric',
    cminorunit varchar(4) default 0 comment 'Minor unit.',
    cname varchar(80) not null comment 'Name of the currency.',
    centity varchar(100) not null comment 'Entity.'
```

Thanks for the help you can give me.

Comment: It's exactly what I need, thank you very much.

Comment: Great, I've moved that to an answer. Please accept once you've tested enough.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always want to capture between the first and last parenthesis this would work:

```
(?s)\(\s*(.*)\s*\)
```

https://regex101.com/r/MVs17e/1/

The `(?s)` makes the `.` match multiple lines. The `.*` is greedy and looks for the last `)`. The backslashes before the parenthesis escape the parenthesis because those are special characters in regex. The `\s*` is zero or more whitespaces so we don't capture the whitespace before/after the encapsulating parenthesis.